# websphere network deployment v8.5.5.0 not scanning annotated web service classes during deployment

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, ejb-3.1

I have a simple ear file containing a war file that has an local ejb class annotated with WebService.

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestWS {
    @WebMethod
    public int meaningoflife() {return 42;}
}
```

my web.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"
         version="3.0">

</web-app>
```

When I deploy this file to my test server (Websphere Application Server v 8.5.5.0 packaged with RAD v9.0) the web services are scanned and deployed and I can see them in the configuration screen and access the wsdl files correctly.

However, When i try to deploy the application to Websphere Application Server Network Deployment v 8.5.5.0, the annotations are ***not*** scanned and i cannot see the web service prodiver configuration settings when i click on the application from the websphere admin console and it's endpoint urls do not resolve.

Curiously, The scanning was activated on a previous (ear) deployment but when i placed that same ear file into the server a second time it failed as well

Because the web.xml shown above is version 3.0, the scanning should occur. and because Websphere 8.5 is fully java ee 6 compliant, it should do it.

setting UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy to true in the manifest.mf doesn't work even though it should scan the class files regardless.

I have been spending days trying to work out the problem and would appreciate anyone with websphere knowledge to point me in a possible direction

**UPDATE:** metadata-complete attribute is defintely false in setup and i additionally ensure that it is left unchecked in deployment.

Comment: I have not tested servlet annotations, but our EJB annotations are working fine in WAS 8.5.5. Have you tried enabling trace logging for the deployment manager? it is a bit difficult to read, but this is the only thing you can do, save for opening a PMR

Answer (score 2):

Check that [**metadata-complete** attribute](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/urun_rapp_metadata_lockdd.html) is disabled in your deployed application.

You can do this from WAS ND Console:

**Enterprise Applications** > **Your App** > **Metadata for modules** > Uncheck the **metadata-complete attribute** checkbox, Synchronize with the Node and restart your App.

If this doesn't do the work uninstall/reinstall the application but be careful to set metadata-complete as disabled during the deployment.

Comment: In your WAS ND env and in your App check that you have not changed the com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.context.filter.* and com.ibm.ws.application.enhancedScanning properties. For a complete guide here: http://wasdynacache.blogspot.gr/2012/05/how-to-speed-up-annotation-processing.html

Comment: unfortunately all of those attributes are not set. I checked the server, profile, jvm args, Manifest.MF, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I spent many days trying to solve this problem. I found the problem when I put the log4j with parameter "**ALL**". After doing that, Websphere 8.5 logged the problems during the deployment of the application with the @WebService annotation.

My problem was that I had classes from other sources in this @WebService class and the *wsgen* doesn't recognize.

The solution was to create a Delegate class that encapsulates my logic.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/" ,serviceName = "MyService", portName = "MyServicePort")
public class MyServiceDelegate {

    my.class.MyService serviceLogic = null;

    public MyServiceDelegate() {
        serviceLogic = new my.class.MyService();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public ExecuteServiceResponse executeService() {
        return serviceLogic.executeService();
    }

}
```

Try moving the @Stateless and @LocalBean annotations to the encapsulated class.